# The best way to obtain images with different resolutions in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm working on Android application that uses ARCore (and Sceneform) and performs detector for each frame and classifier for selected frames. Detector requires rather low resolution frames (640x480 ARCore motion tracking default is enough) but classifier requires at least fullhd. I tried two options:

- `arCoreSession.cameraConfig = config with 640x480 image res` and additional ImageReader with 1920x1080 resolution. It works but I suspect that ImageReader's frame is just upscaled from 640x480. Is it correct?
- `arCoreSession.cameraConfig = config with 1920x1080 image res`. ARCore creates 3 surfaces (gpu fhd, motion tracking 640x480 and cpu 1920x1080), `frame.acquireLatestImage` returns fhd frame. Such behavior is suitable for classifier usecase but converting fhd image from yuv to rgb and resizing to detector's input size take too much time (more than detector inference). Is it possible to acquire motion tracking image in Sceneform onUpdate or ARCore's Frame object?

What is the best practice in my case?

Comment: I'm dealing with this too. My main problem is that the 640x480 is not only smaller (you can work that around by scaling), but it's a different aspect ratio! It's 4:3 instead of 16:9 like the 1920x1080 is! I need an unaugmented 1920x1080 source camera image what the framework uses as a basis for augmentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227417/how-to-obtain-screen-aspect-ratio-camera-image-in-an-arcore-application

Comment: Or lower resolution would also make it, but the same aspect ratio. Or how do I know what portion of the 1920x1080 the upscaled 4:3 image covers?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from yuv to argb using renderscript: https://github.com/android/renderscript-intrinsics-replacement-toolkit

Obtain the camera image (frame.acquireCameraImage) and pass it to this script: https://github.com/android/renderscript-intrinsics-replacement-toolkit/blob/main/test-app/src/main/java/com/google/android/renderscript_test/IntrinsicYuvToRgb.kt